# JMeter recording issues with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'am facing recording issues in **JMeter version 5.0** while using it with **Chrome browser - Version 72.0.3626.96** (Official Build) (64-bit).

I have installed **JMeter Root CA certificate** in my local drive, Also imported that certificate in chrome browser. Still I can't record any request, Which version of chrome is suggestable for recording purpose in JMeter 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

Any version of Chrome should fit, just make sure to [install JMeter's self-signed certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccrypto/creating-viewing-and-managing-certificates) to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`

[image]

Also be aware that JMeter's certificates have limited time frame (7 days by default) so double check that the certificate isn't expired.

If you conducted above steps and still cannot record - try [clearing your browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) (delete everything from the beginning of the time) and re-install the certificate.

---

Going forward I would recommend using a browser which has separate proxy/certificates configuration like [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) which doesn't rely on operating system certificates and proxy settings.

Also you can consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the adding the certificate `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` also ensure the following

1. There is no multiple entries of the JMETER certificated under `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`. If so delete all entries and add the new certificate fresh.
2. Ensure that the expiry date of the certificate is a future date. Normally it is auto generated and will be valid for next 7 days in each cycles. But, just ensure the same.
3. Even then, if the requests are not getting recorded, Clear the browser cache and check again. Or even better take the session in incognito mode.